# Use VCS such like Git to track database content (record) changes?

Tags: database, git, version-control

The DB I'm working on is not that huge, just hundred thousands of records from half dozen of tables. It will be very helpful if I can track table content(record) changes, to help in testing as well as in real business cases.

The goal is to be able to visualize the diffs between versions in GIT or any other tools, such like be able to see instantly field values changes, row adding or deletion etc.

One use case is that I can use this tool to examine the result of an app's update to database in test.

Comment: VCS tools are not made for that but if you find a tool that export the data in files in a consistent way (the real challenge here!), you will be able to commit these files and to follow changes with git.

Comment: I realized that real challenge. I am looking for a way to let GIT track each record easily in the exported CSV files, such like using a composite field made of unique index.

Comment: Do you want version tracking ("diffs between versions") or do you want change notifications ("see instantly field values changes")? You need to pick one because they are very different things.

Comment: I'm looking for the function of "diffs between versions".

Answer (score 1):

#### In Git? Yes and no. Maybe. Probably not.

You could take a **snapshot** of the database in a **stable plain text form**, and commit this snapshot into git. Almost all database systems support exporting tables into one or more plain text forms, e.g. SQL DDL statements or CSV files. By "stable" I mean that the rows and columns are sorted the same between snapshots, otherwise your diffs will not work.

The issue you may run into is file size and git performance. "Just hundred thousands of records" is still a large file in plain text and far larger than the kind of files git is designed for: programming source code. Large files will impact git in many ways: since git blobs are file-level, it means if only a single field in a single row of the table changes, git will store a full copy of the table, not just the minimal diff. Well, git *does* know how to do more [granular diff-based storage](https://gist.github.com/matthewmccullough/2695758), but that is reserved for older history as it trades speed for disk space.

It would be easy enough to test.

#### Using versioned table rows

Usually this is done directly in the database, where instead of updating a row, a new one is inserted and all foreign keys in other tables are updated to point to the new row, and the old row is marked archived.

#### use DB triggers to track changes

Changes can be recorded to a change tracking table, or to an auxiliary database (see next).

#### You could use a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) DB to store snapshots or changes.

- You could store full snapshots of the tables in an auxiliary NoSQL database such as MongoDB. The rows would have a timestamp or version column so that all snapshots could reside in the same table.
- OR you could setup a triggers in your DB that record only update rows in your auxiliary DB.
- If the source tables have update timestamps you can just query for changed rows periodically. Use this if you can't set up a trigger in the DB.

#### Look into what your DB supports natively

You should also look into whether your database platform supports this natively.

Some databases have log files that can be queried.

Comment: In my use case, I have to treat the application subsystem which operates on the DB tables as a black box. My main purpose is to have a utility to observe the changes made by the subsystem in each transaction. Later, I think I can use it to facilitate tests too.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find any options beyond what I've listed, *especially* if you are only allowed a black box view. You can write an application that periodically snapshots the tables (i.e. `select * from table`) and writes it to its own NoSQL instance and then scans for changes. Or see above about using timestamps since you can't insert a trigger into a black box DB.

Comment: @MingD. So did you ever get what you wanted? Or was I right?

Comment: I have not but I am still looking into it. So far, I have to export those tables as CSV and write specific Python code to find out data changes between tables of different exports.